# how do I determine how much VRAM is in the system?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I just bought a Samsung Series 7 laptop but I have no idea how much VRAM the graphics card has.  This is an NVIDIA OPTIMUS card.  I am using Windows 7 and will upgrade to 8 within the hour.

I switched from Mac to PC. So its not familiar to me. I am sorry that you guys know where to look and think this question is very trivial. Someone is selling me his laptop and claims it has 1GB VRAM. The stock # says it should have 512MB and I wanted to verify these details.

Comment: Have you run dxdiag in the Run command ?

Comment: Its only showing the Intel card. How do I get it to show the Nvidia card?

Comment: I downloaded the tool. Where do I look for the VRAM?

Comment: Added the path in AIDA64 to help you find the memory utilization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have an Nvidia card, you should be able to get that information from the Nvidia control panel.

1. Right-click on the desktop and choose **NVIDIA Control Panel** to bring it up (or go into the start menu).
2. Go to the **Help -> System Information** menu.
3. Look at the **Dedicated video memory** in the **Display** tab under the **Details** list.

[image]

---

Alternatively if for whatever reason you don't have that available to you, you can look at the system information to get the numbers.

1. Press <kbd>Win + R</kbd> to open the **Run** dialog and enter: **msinfo32**.
2. Then view the **System Summary -> Components -> Display** view and look for the **Adapter RAM**.  You'll find the ram size there.

[image]

Comment: MSINFO32 shows Intel HD 4000. I updated to Windows 8 so I am reinstalling the NVidia drivers

Comment: NVidia Control panel is showing 4GB. I know that thats not possible because the unit can have 512GB or 1GB VRAM.

Comment: I don't know how the Optimus actually works or how it affects the readings but it could be possible that the card could be using system memory as well or something along those lines. Do all the other memory readings read similarly?

Answer (score 1):

You should run

```
dxdiag
```

in the search right on top of the start menu (Run input field) . Or you can install somethin like [AIDA64 (Everest)](http://www.lavalys.com/) that will scan the hardware and give you detailled information about every component on your PC. You can find the video card utilisation under

```
Display -> GPU
```

You'll be able to see on your right complete information about your video card and even see the current utilization. Just start a game to see how much memories it takes to run it live.

Answer (score 0):

[GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) should also be able to help:

[image: 1] [image: 2]

Answer (score -1):

Where in that picture does it say vram? Why not explain it for people who are new to gaming and the lingo who are trying to learn these things but the internet is bulging with info just not the information needed. It has many answers but not the one that answers the question when you need it. Oh and there are many pages that look like the answer but when you click on it it is completely different content its a good thing a danger warning pops up for me but it add to the frustration.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1088711)